# integration of Jmeter with HP ALM

Tags: performance, jmeter, continuous-integration, alm

I want to run the JMeter application relevant script with help of HP ALM and later want to integrate with Jenkins. How to run jmeter scripts from HP ALM, I would be so grateful.

Answer (score 0):

1. For running scripts from ALM check out official  [Run JMeter Tests from Performance Center](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/pc/en/12.56/online_help/Content/PC/JMeter-Scripts.htm) manual
2. For running tests from Jenkins - there are too many possible options depending on your build toolchain, the most basic use case - [FreeStyle Project](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project) and [JMeter from command line non-GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) you just need to add [`Execute Shell`](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Shells) build step and put your command to kick off a JMeter test there.

   [image: JMeter run in Jenkins]

   See [Continuous Integration 101: How to Run JMeter With Jenkins](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/continuous-integration-101-how-run-jmeter-jenkins) for more details.